# How to get Chrome to rollup/rolldown when double clicking the titlebar?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu, not Ubuntu 2D, on Kubuntu 11.10.

Every application except Chrome abides by the toggle_shade setting I have when double-clicking the titlebar.  How do I get Chrome to behave like the other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Chrome (and Chromium) draws its own title bar and borders, so it doesn't always behave like other applications.  You can configure it to use a standard title bar though with the following steps:

1. right click on an empty area of the tab bar at the top of the window.
2. pick the `Use System Title Bar and Borders` option.

This does change the appearance a little, but does give you a title bar that behaves like other applications.